# HOW TO: Get the Item Selected in NavigationView in C++

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx, navigationview

I'm new to UWP and I have what I think is a simple problem to solve, but the examples I've found haven't worked. I'm using a navigation view in UWP project and I want to be able to switch page and display in a frame. When I select an item in the navigation view the ItemInvoked event is fired. I know the code to load the page into the frame which I've included below.

```
void enVigilServer::MainPage::nvSample_ItemInvoked(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs^ args)
{

this->contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(SysConf::typeid));

}
```

My problem is how to determine which item I've selected from the NavigationView to show the relevant page.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, UWP is not supported by C++. Are you asking about C++/CX?

Comment: There's a VC++ UWP project wizard in VS2017.

Comment: Sure, but, it doesn't mean that it uses C++, instead of one of MS C++-offshoots, such as C++/CX, or C++/CLI. For instance `Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView^ sender` is invalid, in function argument list, in C++, due to `^` being XOR operator.

Comment: OK, should i use c# then?

Comment: There is tag called [tag:c++-cx], that you can tag with if it is C++/CX. However, I am not that familiar with MS C++-like offshoots, so I am not certain whether it is [tag:c++-cx], [tag:c++-cli], or any other variant.. C++/CX description, however, suggests that it is, what is being used here ("_is a set of high-level language extensions for C++ to work with the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)_").

Answer (score 1):

It's actually related to c++-cx and I will purpose this tag to your issue.

To make the navigation simple we can use the tag system in our app. See the following code:

```
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl" ItemInvoked="NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked" >
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="A" x:Name="A" Tag="tga" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="B" x:Name="B" Tag="tgb"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="C" x:Name="C" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
```

This is an example, we will add tags to our items. Then we will do the following in our invoke code:

```
void NavigationVWCX::MainPage::NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs^ args)
{
    auto navitemtag = args->InvokedItemContainer->Tag->ToString();
    if (navitemtag == "tga")
    {
        contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(PageA::typeid));
    }
    if (navitemtag == "tgb")
    {
        contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(PageB::typeid));
    }   
}
```

BTW, don't forget to also add tag to your pages, like:

```
PageB::PageB()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this->Tag = "tgb";
}
```

Comment: Also c++/winrt is on the way and it is the latest suggest way to coding in C++, you can consider it in the future. And as you are new to uwp, you may also give c# a try 
since c# contains more samples for your reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Comment: Thanks, however InvokedItemContainer isn't a member of NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs.

Comment: @NOZ77 That is because it is newly created on 17763 and you'd better upgrade your SDK version to this latest version.